# Can I focus php to type the variable class in php?

Tags: java, php, object

In Java, everything object, I know which type it is, for example... I will doing something like this:

```
MyObject aObject = new MyObject();
```

I always know that the "aObject" is MyObject...

but PHP, I use this

```
$aObject = new MyObject();
```

I don't know what is the "aObject" was, I try to doing this, it gives me error:

```
MyObject $aObject = new MyObject();
```

It makes me feel very focus on that, any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: use comments that will make you remember

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make great use of comments like that

```
// data type is MyObject
$aObject = new MyObject();
```

Comment: it's better to use phpdoc comments: `/* @var $aObject MyObject */`, then the auto-completion will work in IDEs.

Comment: There is always room for something better :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read [PHP: Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), and [PHP: Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) on php.net.

Answer (score 1):

That is, unfortunatley for you, how PHP works. There are no strict data-types in PHP, what so ever. It is something that you have to grow into to be a PHP-programmer.

Comment: I agree with you and I understand your problem. You should just dive into it and learn how it works.

Answer (score 0):

No, in PHP you can do Type juggling:

```
$aObject = new MyObject();
$aObject = new UnrelatedObject();
```

is perfectly valid PHP. It's not necessarily a bad thing though. It has both pros and cons.